# Safari doesn't set the JavaScript variable properly

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I'm on Safari 12.0.3. I have:

```js
function doThisOnlyOnce() {
  if (MyNamespace.firstUserGesture) {
    console.log('Do stuff only once!')
  }
  MyNamespace.firstUserGesture = false
}

function init() {
  window.MyNamespace = {} // Easy access to some vars.
  MyNamespace.firstUserGesture = true

  MyNamespace.vid = document.getElementById("vid")
  MyNamespace.vid.addEventListener('click', doThisOnlyOnce)
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="vid">x</div>
</body>
```

## Problem

On Safari, `doThisOnlyOnce()` is run on every click. `MyNamespace.firstUserGesture` is *not* set to `false` at all.

On any other browser `doThisOnlyOnce()` is run on the first click only, as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Mac OS Safari or iOS Safari? (Or both?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I removed the *mobile-safari* tag. I can only confirm for desktop Safari at this point :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's very strange. But here on this StackOverflow post when I run the code snippet with the same Safari `12` browser, the function is run only once! I'm confused :(

Comment: @user3405291 Clearly your local code is different in some way to the code you posted here on SO

Comment: It seems exceptionally unlikely that Safari is broken in such a fundamental way, which suggests there's more going on. For instance, if you have invalid HTML markup (putting `p` elements inside `span` elements, that kind of thing), the ways different browsers "fix" it when building the DOM is not always 100% consistent across browser vendors. I suspect that's what's going on here. On Safari, I suggest right-clicking the `vid` element and choosing "Inspect" (or whatever it's called on Safari) to look at the **actual DOM** (not view source). Sounds like the click is reloading the page.

Comment: @DavidCallanan The function is defined for `click` event of a simple `div` tag :(

Comment: Although I can't imagine why this may make a difference, I would suggest not using inline event attributes, such as `onload` and stick with `.addEventListener()`. You might also consider using `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `Load` for your event binding.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Alright, let met check!

Comment: @ScottMarcus I removed `onload="init()"` and created a `<script>` tag at the end, containing `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init)`. Unfortunately, the behaviour is the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the code line-by-line with Safari JS debugger indicates that one of the statements of `doThisOnlyOnce` function was throwing an exception. Removing the exception cause, also removed this strange behavior too.

Comment: For some reason, other browsers are NOT throwing that exception.